# Object.entries в TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-типы

Как преобразовать этот тип:

```
{
    a: number
    b: string
    c: number
}
```

В этот:

```
[['a', number], ['b', string], ['c', number]]
```

Т.е. эффект 1 в 1 как от `Object.entries`, только вместо значений св-в их типы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного модифицировав [код, переводящий `union` тип, в `tuple`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-675386981) - можно получить ожидаемый результат. Однако, так как `union` тип не упорядочен, есть вероятность, что порядок элементов в `tuple` может меняться:

```
type TuplePrepend<Tuple extends readonly unknown[], NewElement> =
    [NewElement, ...Tuple]

type Consumer<Value> = (value: Value) => void;

type IntersectionFromUnion<Union> = 
    (Union extends unknown ? Consumer<Union> : never) extends (Consumer<infer ResultIntersection>)
    ? ResultIntersection
    : never;

type OverloadedConsumerFromUnion<Union> = IntersectionFromUnion<Union extends unknown ? Consumer<Union> : never>;

type UnionLast<Union> = OverloadedConsumerFromUnion<Union> extends ((a: infer A) => void) ? A : never;

type UnionExcludingLast<Union> = Exclude<Union, UnionLast<Union>>;

type TupleFromUnionRec<RemainingUnion, CurrentTuple extends readonly unknown[], TObj extends Record<any, any>> =
    [RemainingUnion] extends [never]
    ? CurrentTuple
    : TupleFromUnionRec< // рекурсивный тип
        UnionExcludingLast<RemainingUnion>, 
        TuplePrepend<
          CurrentTuple, 
          [UnionLast<RemainingUnion>, TObj[UnionLast<RemainingUnion>]] // добавляем тип ключа с типом значения в конечный tuple
        >, 
        TObj>;

export type TupleFromUnion<TObj> = TupleFromUnionRec<keyof TObj, [], TObj>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oEMBcUB2ArgLYBGEATgNxoYm4DOw5AlngObUZQDGuhpFagF8UKUJCgAVAmAA2EAArkIkPABMAPNLnQIAD2AR19KMsxqA9nlkgoBPAGs8FgO54A2gF0ANFAByEC4AovJERsAAfAg06O4BwaHhvgB0qdrynqLi0ADCVvTEFBoAapiyBBBRiAAUAG5lFbil5RAAlAhRtRbMatRi4NAAkniG5PQQ3MDMVgBi5BZEAKp403gay6tVMVDVG1ZQ+obGdo7OblAA-FB5eAVh5OsrVlF8ELUU7YdGaibVN3dFVgAMwoUAAShACrJgMNRuNJptWtsrhCoTCRhR4VMrNtXu8qFkBlAAPL42QWcwQNT-QrkOYLPZrRlVKCwzETbF4elLJ5M3kHAzfEz2JyuPCXa75WmPTZQPEUCJ9bJQRkAGUwjBlzwQJLJFLUVJp925jK1eCiX2O1WqOCgwNBMHa8E63TU7SucHlBP6EkZQT03HKalYbHVmuZOv9gYIBrNvjVGuAZoiisJEnSEBNvIh3A0EKImFYIcZvhyBHIyhGGYFRx+pgg5isNhOorcXl8kmJJAAVjWheCJhZyJpMHgQL5RyAU9EuO584WVuxGZ4+8d3Hg3hRMlwrmWK+EM7ipDJ5FnVjmzVGgyGw0n50Wl7yIh2T4plKpNHvK8AM753AnNXvRc2GZDsu27f9eVvPMIALB8QKfTxPGfKRwNTFB9DAIdgCgZUMzPKwtDQnV8PmHlzwmDQHAgEALCBVCez-HwGO7dDuHyHDwhYSFiSBGBcFIhleQ0GAWXcdwAHJMAk3wAEZmMkkgZKgCS1DUiSFIk7hlPkzw+hQIA)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130122/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy-object-entries--typescript).